Can this code be simplified further?
This is the code:
labels = {MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], #2, {-1, -2}] &, {{"A", 
     "A1", "B", "B1", "C", "C1", "P", "Q", "N"}, {a, a1, b, b1, c, c1,
      p[t], q[t], n}}]}

(*{{Text["A",a,{-1,-2}],Text["A1",a1,{-1,-2}],Text["B",b,{-1,-2}],\
Text["B1",b1,{-1,-2}],Text["C",c,{-1,-2}],Text["C1",c1,{-1,-2}],Text[\
"P",p[t],{-1,-2}],Text["Q",q[t],{-1,-2}],Text["N",n,{-1,-2}]}}*)

Can this code be simplified further?

No... it can't.

This is personal style. I never like long chained commands. I like to make variables and small functions.
It makes it easier for me to read my own code one week after I write it.
So I would write your code using 4 lines instead of your one long complicated line.
e1 = {a, a1, b, b1, c, c1, p[t], q[t], n};
e2 = {"A", "A1", "B", "B1", "C", "C1", "P", "Q", "N"};
f[a_, b_] := Text[Style[a, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {-1, -2}]

labels = {MapThread[f[#1, #2] &, {e1, e2}]}

For me, the above is much more clear than
labels = {MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], #2, {-1, -2}] &, {{"A", 
     "A1", "B", "B1", "C", "C1", "P", "Q", "N"}, {a, a1, b, b1, c, c1,
      p[t], q[t], n}}]}

I know it is more cool to write one program using just one very very long command that has 5 commands inside it, but for me ease of reading and understanding of code is more important than being cool and short.
But again, this is just personal style. May be for others, your long command is more clear. I do not know.

I think Nasser is right : it was a time (at least 25 years ago) where one-liners were 'à la mode' , so it seems that some people
still like them which makes code totally unreadable. Cryptic code is never a good idea.

If you don't like MapThread, you can make the pure function Listable and apply it directly to the two lists:
labels = {Function[Null, 
    Text[Style[#1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], #2, {-1, -2}], 
    Listable][{"A", "A1", "B", "B1", "C", "C1", "P", "Q", "N"}, {a, 
    a1, b, b1, c, c1, p[t], q[t], n}]}

Of course, this won't quite work right if the function is supposed to be able to take lists as input.
